# How to edit the text that appears on the Unity login screen?

Tags: unity, login-screen

I was previously using Ubuntu 13.04 and had done PostgreSQL Advanced Server installation which edited my Unity login screen to include its title. I've since uninstalled that proprietary version of Postgres but the login screen remains the same. I have also upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04, but the text still appears for me.

How to edit the text that appears on the Unity login screen?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 is EOL, please upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: done... any thoughts on editing the login screen text?

Comment: This is on-topic now ...but still needs clarification. Can you give details about the previous installation, what the old title was exactly, and what the screen that you no longer want looks like (unless the title is the only difference). Also, to clarify, since as far as I know there isn't anything ordinarily called "the Unity login screen"--do you mean the login screen that appears when you start your computer, where you enter or select your username and enter your password to get a graphical login session (which itself may be a Unity session)? Or do you mean something else altogether?

Comment: yes, the screen where I enter my login and password to start my Unity session. The Postgres installation put a "Postgres Advanced Server" title above the login box. Compared to the normal login screen, that title is the only difference and is the text I want to remove. A nag, yes, but if it was edited it can be re-edited, no?

Answer (score 0):

Although the version of ubuntu you reference is obsolete and completely EOL, you might try doing a reinstall of lightdm with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm`

Comment: i upgraded to 14.04 and tried the reinstall lightdm, but no luck.